# PHP Google API - Missing scope

Tags: php, google-api, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I'm using the following, based on Google's calendar sample app which worked fine.

```
    $client = new \Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName("Google Calendar PHP Starter Application");
    $client->setClientId('myclientid.apps.googleusercontent.com');
    $client->setClientSecret('mysecret');
    $client->setRedirectUri('http://localhost/admin/index.php?m=1&e=calendar');
    $client->setDeveloperKey('mykey');

    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    }

    if (!$client->getAccessToken()) {
        $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        header('Location: ' . $authUrl);
    }
```

But I'm getting:

```
Error: invalid_request
Missing required parameter: scope
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Was missing this line after I set the developerKey

```
$cal = new \Google_CalendarService($client);
```

I guess the act of getting a calendar service from the client sets the scope.  Pretty reasonable.

Comment: Thank you!! Trying to figure this out using <sarcasm>Google's amazingly good documentation</sarcasm> wasn't working out so well.